# How to add a constant custom header to Message Mediation in wso2 apim publisher?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am testing wso2 apim 4.0.0. I have a rest api published and I would like to send custom header to the backend. By following [the official documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend/) a mediation file created with following contents:

```
<sequence name="test7" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"> 
<property name="custom-header" value="123456" scope="transport" action="set"/>
</sequence>
```

The sequence above is uploaded to request mediation as depicted in the following pic:
[image]

In my backend api I am printing all headers to make sure the existence of the custom header. It's showing all headers but the custom header:

```
{activityid=b8cd086c-18df-4067-9790-900a1fc1a2f1, accept=*/*, host=localhost:8080, connection=Keep-Alive, user-agent=Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO}
```

I would like to see my custom-header among above headers as following:

{activityid=b8cd086c-18df-4067-9790-900a1fc1a2f1, accept=*/*, host=localhost:8080, **custom-header=123456**, connection=Keep-Alive, user-agent=Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO}

Answer (score 0):

Few possible mistakes you made. Make sure you add the Custom Policy to the request flow.

[image]

After adding the policy did you deploy a new revision of the API for the new changes to be deployed?

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did it the exact same way, namely: 1. created mediation policy; attached to request flow as custom, saved and deployed with new revision. Nothing changed though